# PFQuery for Top 10 Max scorers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, parse-platform, xcode5

I am new to Parse.

I am using Parse in my app. I have a class which stores scores of users. Now, I want to get Top 10 maximum scorer. How can I?
Please Help!

Down Voters Please answer!

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted so far.

Comment: @Pork I don't know how to do it. I think I should get all the records and then sort it descending order and get first 10 record.

Comment: You'll have to show us at least what fields you have and your class names. But you really should attempt to solve the problem first, show us your work and we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not so hard, just take a look at the [docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS).

But, anyway, you should probably do something like this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];
[query orderByDescending:@"score"];
query.limit = 10;
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
  } else {
  }
}];
```